# Create a seasaw in Box2d for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, box2d

On one side of the seesaw i have a bomb, and I want the following to happen:

When something, anything, hits the OTHER side of the seesaw, i'd like the bomb to go flying, like in real life. But after the bomb flies, I ALSO need to seesaw to reset itself to its straight position...

How would I do this?

Comment: why not post this as a job over elance??... this is Stackoverflow.. please post your specific code problem... post what you have done yet..and where are you getting issues read FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I've gotten the seesaw working, but when something hits it it falls to the ground